# You'll find it if you go along the

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

**Hidden below is a word. Which word is it?**

---

```
                         (α-β)
                       --------

                       (AC)(LZ)
                       (AG)(PZ)
                       (SX)(GR)
                       (QC)(LP)
                       (XJ)(SW)
                       (BH)(QA)
                       (JT)(CI)
                       (SD)(MR)
                       
                       
                           
                   [][][][][][][][]
                   [][][][][][][][]
                   [][][][][][][][]
                   [][][][][][][][]
                   [][][][][][][][]
                   [][][][][][][][]
                   [][][][][][][][]
                   [][][][][][][][]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The word is

> **diagonal**

Explanation:

> (α-β) shows the two Greek letters alpha and beta, therefore hinting toward the alphabet.
>
>  And indeed, the alphabet is represented by each pair of parenthesized letters... but only partially. For example, (AC)(LZ) represents the letters from A to C, then L to Z. To complete the alphabet, we take the skipped letters: D, E, F, G, H, I, J, and K.
>
>  Doing this for each pair of parenthesized letters (going back to A if we reach a Z), we get this:
>
> ```
>     (AC) D E F G H I J K (LZ)
>     (AG) H I J K L M N O (PZ)
>     (SX) Y Z A B C D E F (GR)
>     (QC) D E F G H I J K (LP)
>     (XJ) K L M N O P Q R (SW)
>     (BH) I J K L M N O P (QA)
>     (JT) U V W X Y Z A B (CI)
>     (SD) E F G H I J K L (MR)
> ```

> and so we have an 8x8 grid of letters which corresponds with the given blank 8x8 grid.
>
>  And finally, notice that the word "diagonal" is written along the main... diagonal! Hence the title is completed with the answer itself: "You'll find it if you go along the *diagonal.*"

Comment: Correct. Well done!